# Why helicity is proportional to the spin of particle and has two values?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, poincare-symmetry, helicity

How can it be shown without using the little group formalism?

Let's have the Wigner's classification for the irreducible represetation of the Poincare group. For the massless case the eigenvalues of two Casimir operators of the group, the squares of Pauli-Lubanski operator and momentum operator, $\hat {W}_{\alpha}W^{\alpha}, \hat {P}_{\alpha}\hat {P}^{\alpha}$, is equal to zero.

Together with $\hat {W}_{\alpha}\hat {P}^{\alpha} = 0$ it leads to an expression $\hat {W}_{\alpha} = \hat {h}\hat {P}_{\alpha}$, where eigenvalues of $\hat {h}$ has dimension like angular momentum. It is called helicity. I want to get it "properties" without using small groups formalism (by the other words, not as Weinberg).

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance . Let's have the Wigner's classification for the irreducible represetation of the Poincare group. For the massless case the eigenvalues of two Casimir operators of the group, the squares of Pauli-Lubanski operator and momentum operator, $\hat {W}_{\alpha}W^{\alpha}, \hat {P}_{\alpha}\hat {P}^{\alpha}$, is equal to zero.

Comment: Sorry, I slightly misunderstood the point of your question. But it is good to have a fuller characterization.

Comment: Together with $\hat {W}_{\alpha}\hat {P}^{\alpha} = 0$ it leads to an expression $\hat {W}_{\alpha} = h\hat {P}_{\alpha}$, where $h$ has dimension like angular momentum. It is called helicity. I want to get it "properties" without using small groups formalism (by the other words, not as Weinberg).

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid Weinberg? I have to imagine what you're doing amounts to computing the little group in a more formal way. In any case, I know that Weinberg's derivation that the helicity of massless particles has two values relies on topological considerations--it is not enough to think about infintesimal transformations and thus not enough to think about the action of the generators. I imagine that even if you find an alternative derivation than Weinberg's, it will not get around this fact, you will have to consider the topology of the group somehow.

Comment: Maybe you should change the title of your question. Helicity is a measured fact, like other measurements that describe elementary interaction in real nature. Theoretical formulations attempt to describe this reality. The question sounds as if you are talking about the definition of helicity, which is an experimental observable.

Comment: @PhysiXxx: For a massless particle, helicity and chirality are the same thing.  Chirality is determined by whether the particle transforms in a right or left-handed representation (of the Lorentz group). That is : representations $(h,0)$ have chirality $h$, while representations $(0,h)$ have chirality $-h$.

Comment: @Annav . "...Theoretical formulations attempt to describe this reality...", - it is a question of interpretation. Helicity values (and spin values) can get in theoretical formalism (only more generally) just like experimentally.

Comment: @Trimok . "...For a massless particle, helicity and chirality are the same thing...", - why?

Comment: @Andrew . Maybe you're right. But I don't want to learn more paragraphs from Weinberg book, so want to find more simple method.

Comment: Theoretical formalism is pure mathematics unless it is modeling nature. It becomes physics only then.  There can be n theoretical formalisms,where n is a large number, quite useless for physics interpretation. It is the observations that define physical quantities in the end, not the mathematics.

Comment: @PhysiXxx : For massive particle, as electrons, helicity depends on the frame. Suppose you electron has some speed $v_z$.If you take a new frame which speed relatively to the electron which is positive, you will have an opposite helicity than if you take a frame which speed relatively to the electron is negative. Now, for massless particles, you cannot have a frame which speed is greater than $c$, so the helicity/chirality is constant, and in fact is coming from the representations of the Lorentz group.

Comment: @Trimok . "...That is : representations (h,0) have chirality h, while representations (0,h) have chirality −h...", - is it postulate?

Comment: @PhysiXxx : No, chirality is defined following group theory. Left-handed chiral representations, and right-handed chiral representations have opposite chirality.

Comment: @Trimok . I.e., I can show, that left fermion's massless state has helicity $\frac{\hbar}{2}$, right state - $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$, by using Dirac equation and it's solution. Also, maybe, I can show analogical thing ($\hbar, -\hbar$) for photon. But how can it be generalized?

Comment: "...No, chirality is defined following group theory. Left-handed chiral representations, and right-handed chiral representations have opposite chirality...", - and where can I read about this, if you please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Construction of the helicity formula using 3-vector notation

The zero component of the pauli Lubanski vector

$W^0 = \epsilon^{0 ijk}J_{ij}p_k = \epsilon^{ijk}J_{ij}p_k $

The angular momentum genrerators

$ j^k =  \epsilon^{ijk}J_{ij}$

Thus

$W^0 = j^k p_k = \vec{j}.\vec{p} $

The orbital angular momentum

$ \vec{l} = \vec{x} \times \vec{p}$

is orthogonal to the momentum:

$ \vec{l}.\vec{p} = 0$

And since the total angular momentum is the vector sum of the orbirtal and the spin angular momenta

$ \vec{j} =  \vec{l} + \vec{\Sigma}$

Thus

$W^0 = j^k p_k = \vec{j}.\vec{p} = (\vec{j-l}).\vec{p} = \vec{\Sigma}.\vec{p} $

Now, since

$W^0 = \hat{h} p_0$

and  for a massless particle

$ p_0 = p$

We obtain:

$ \hat{h} = \frac{\vec{\Sigma}.\vec{p}}{p_0} = \vec{\Sigma}.\hat{p}$

1. The helicity operator

$$\hat{h} = \Sigma.\hat{p}$$

where $\Sigma$ is the spin operator and $\hat{p}$ is the momentum unit vector is a projection along the axis $\hat{p}$ of a spin operator, thus one might expect it to have for a helicity $\lambda$ the eigenvalues $\lambda$, $\lambda-1$, ..., $-\lambda$.

However, the eigenvectors corresponding to all eigenvalues except $\pm \lambda$ are not physical, because they describe longitudinal polarizations which do not exist in free massless particles.

Here is an example of the massless spin-1 case (photon). In this case, we may choose the spin operators as:

$ \Sigma_x = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &  0& 0\\ 
0 &  0& -i\\ 
0 &  i& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$\Sigma_y = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &  0& i\\ 
0 &  0& 0\\ 
-i &  0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$\Sigma_z = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &  -i & 0\\ 
i &  0& 0\\ 
0 &  0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

The action of the Helicity operator on (say), the electric field in the momentum representation is:

$$\hat{h} \vec{E} = i\begin{bmatrix}
0 &  -\hat{p}_z & \hat{p}_y\\ 
\hat{p}_z &  0& -\hat{p}_x\\ 
-\hat{p}_x &  \hat{p}_x& 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
E_x\\ 
E_y\\ 
E_z
\end{bmatrix} =  i \hat{p}\times \vec{E}$$

Thus:

$$\hat{h}^2 \vec{E} = - \hat{p} \times ( \hat{p}\times \vec{E}) = \vec{E} -\hat{p}(\hat{p}. \vec{E})$$

But, since for a free electromagnetic field:

$$\hat{p}. \vec{E} = 0$$

We get:

$$\hat{h}^2 = 1$$,

and the only admissible eigenvalues are $\pm 1$

Comment: "...The helicity operator $\hbar = \Sigma \hat {p}...$, from where did you take this definition?

Comment: "... the eigenvectors corresponding to all eigenvalues except ±λ are not physical, because they describe longitudinal polarizations which do not exist in free massless particles...", - can it be generalized without using examples?

Comment: @PhysiXxx I have added an update showing the computation of the helicity in 3-vector notation. The generalization of the case of the electromagnetic field (that I know of) requires the use of spinor notation of the massless field equations. It requires more than a few lines. I'll try to find a good reference.

Comment: Thank you! "...I'll try to find a good reference...". I would be grateful.

Comment: But there is a question about derivation an expression of helicity operator. How did you avoid problem with $\hat {p}_{0}$ (by the other words - interpreting it as a scalar) when passing from
$$
\hat {W}^{0} = \hat {h}\hat {p}^{0}
$$
to
$$
\hat {h} = \frac{\hat {W}^{0}}{p_{0}}?
$$
You used something like
$$
\hat {W}^{0}\psi = \hat {h}\hat {p}^{0}\psi = \hat {h}p^{0}\psi \Rightarrow \hat {h}\psi = \frac{\hat {W}^{0}}{p^{0}}\psi ? 
$$

Comment: We can talk about two values of helicity which is equal to $\pm s$ only in a case of conservation of parity in a theory. If neutrino is massless, it has only one helicity value, because weak interaction doesn't conserve parity. But I don't know how to discuss about helicity in a case of free fields.

Comment: @PhysiXxx The way I see it is that the computation of the helicity operator is classical, and since the energy of a massless particle is never zero, one may divide by it. After obtaining the classical expression, we quantize according the rules of canonical quantization

Comment: @PhysiXxx The helicity eigenvalue in contrast to that of the spin projection indicates the identity of the particle. For example a photon with a positive helicity is a different particle from a photon with a negative helicity. This is because different helicities correspond to different representations of the Poincare' group. This can also be seen in the photon's Fock space where different helicity photons have different creation and annihilation operators.