# Chirality and helicity operators for the massless bispinor rep and their generalisation on arbitrary (tensor, 4-vector etc) cases

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-spin, chirality, helicity

Let's have chirality projection operator
$$
\hat {C}_{\pm} = \frac{1 \pm \gamma^{5}}{2}.
$$
We introduce it and called it chirality, because
$$
\hat {C}_{+}\psi =  \begin{pmatrix} \psi_{\alpha} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \hat {C}_{-}\psi = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \eta^{\alpha} \end{pmatrix},
$$
which accords to the definition of left- and right-handed spinor (by the classification of irreducible representations of the Lorentz group).

Then let's have helicity projection operator:
$$
\hat {h} = \frac{ 1 \pm \left(\hat {\mathbf S} \cdot \hat {\mathbf p}_{\mathbf 1}\right)}{2}, \quad \hat {\mathbf p}_{1} = \frac{\hat {\mathbf p}}{|\mathbf p|}. 
$$
It can be showed, that for the case $v = c$, where $v$ is the speed of the particle, these operators acts on bispinor the same way. So for bispinor formalism in a massless case helicity and spirality are the same.

But I don't know how to show analogical thing for the particles of different spines (and, according to this, different irreducible Lorentz reps). Maybe, the answer is in the words below?

We can construct different reps of Lorentz group by using spinor formalism. We can construct rep $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ by $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right)\times \left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$, rep $\left(0, 0\right) +\left(1, 0\right)$ by $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right) \times \left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$. So, maybe, we can generalize the calculations with chirality and helicity for the bispinor case on arbitrary cases? If yes, how exactly we can do it?

Related questions: [Chirality, helicity and their relationship for the massless case](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74142/chirality-helicity-and-their-relationship-for-the-massless-case) , [Why helicity is proportional to the spin of particle and has two values?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73911/why-helicity-is-proportional-to-the-spin-of-particle-and-has-two-values) .

Comment: For a massless particle sign of helicity is independent of Lorentz frame. This can be understood by the usual argument that you can't overtake a particle moving at the speed of light and so if projection of its spin in one frame is found to have positive (respectively negative) value, then in any other frame too it will be found to be positive (negative).

Comment: So now if we consider space of eigenstates of helicity operator for a massless particle then since Lorentz transformations do not change the sign of helicity so the eigenstates with positive and negative eigenvalues will separately form a representation of Lorentz group. You may call them two chiral representations if you want.

Comment: @user10001 . These arguments don't forbid helicity values $s - 1, ..., -(s - 1)$. So at least in the massless case helicity can't be identified with chirality.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand. Is there anything wrong with above argument?

Comment: @user10001 . How did you explain the absense of helicity values $s - 1, ... , -(s - 1)$ (as values of the spin operator)? Sometimes it is explained by an argument of absense of longitudinal polarizations in the massless particles, but I didn't see the proof for cases of arbitrary spins.

Comment: sorry I still don't understand how absense or presence of helicity values s-1,..., -(s-1) is relevant to the question of relation between chirality and helicity.

Comment: @user10001 . Let's have 1-spin representation. For the massless case the helicity operator (as projection of spin operator) may have three eigenvalues: $1, 0, -1$. So even in this case I don't know how to identify it with the chirality operator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10152/discussion-between-user10001-and-physixxx)

Comment: @user10001 . I'm agree.