# Why Lagrangian of electromagnetism with Lorenz Gauge evolve Klein Gordon equation?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, klein-gordon-equation, gauge, lorentz-symmetry

Simply Lagrangian without a source for Maxwell equation is
$$
L = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}
$$
Also [Lorenz Gauge condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition) is 
$$
\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}=0
$$
and if so I can briefly add this into Lagrangian like
$$
L = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu})^2
$$
and such a Lagrangian have equations of motions like below:
$$
\partial_\nu\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu}=0
$$
Actually this is Klein-Gordon for massless particles, right? So it means I have a massless and spin-0 particle. What does it mean? Am I getting something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of motion is

$$\partial^2 A_\mu = 0$$

which in fact is a set of four KG equations, one for each field $A_\mu$, $(\mu = 0,\dots,3)$.

This gives us four degrees of freedom for the $A_\mu$ field. But this cannot describe the electromagnetism, since the light has only two degrees of freedom (polarization).

We must not forget that we have set a gauge condition, $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$, which removes a degree of freedom. The other degree of freedom is removed using another contraints.

Comment: So here I do not have a scalar field but 4-component massless vector field instead. Since I know photon have 2 dof I should cut the dof down 2. To get this I have to quantize the vector field. I mean I need to write this A vector field as a superposition of incoming and outgoing waves.

Comment: so I can not tell KG equation only for spin 0 particles? or rather I would say only scalar fields should have spin-0 particles? I do not quite get how a field derived from a spin-1(photon) particle can be a solution of KG?

Answer (score 0):

yes, we have massless particle but not spin zero because ***A*** has 4 index.so it is basically four fields. but for EM we have only two states of polarization so it is cut down to two only not four. for refrence see peskin book.

Comment: polarization of photon is another mystery for me. I know that it has 2 polarization states which are perpendicular to the direction of motion. Is this because of the spin of the photon? And based on your answer A is a massless 4 component vector field but what are these components? Maybe my questions seem a little bit silly sorry for this.

Comment: @Major_Tom about photon's spin see also [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46643/why-is-the-s-z-0-state-forbidden-for-photons).