# What is the value of $W_\mu W^\mu$ for massless particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, poincare-symmetry, helicity

What is the value of the quantity $W_\mu W^\mu$ for massless particles where $W^\mu$ is called [Pauli-Lubanski vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli%E2%80%93Lubanski_pseudovector) defined as $W^\mu=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}P_\nu J_{\alpha\beta}$.

It is trivial to see that $W^\mu P_\mu=0$ and in addition for massless particles $P_\mu P^\mu=0$ holds true. For the massless case, we can choose $P=(p,0,0,p)$ which gives $pW^0=pW^3$ or $W^0=W^3$. Therefore, $W_\mu W^\mu=-(W^1)^2-(W^2)^2$ which is not necessarily zero. But in order to show $W^\mu=\lambda P^\mu$ i.e., $W^\mu$ and $P^\mu$ are linearly dependent we assume $W_\mu W^\mu=0$ or $W^\mu$ to be lightlike. See the paragraph above Eq. B.50 [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nfpADwAAQBAJ&pg=PA514&lpg=PA514&dq=The%20states%20of%20free,%20massive%20particles%20within%20a%20single%20representation%20can%20be%20characterised%20by%20their%20momentum&source=bl&ots=-j0eFMDCbr&sig=ACfU3U0MVZWGLMLs-RfyFVyQPncpoSvfrQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-lJPvxZfmAhUHzDgGHQIIA4YQ6AEwCXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20states%20of%20free%2C%20massive%20particles%20within%20a%20single%20representation%20can%20be%20characterised%20by%20their%20momentum&f=false).

What is the actual value of this for massless particles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $W^2$ is a Casimir of the Poincaré group that is independent of $P^2$, it is not uniquely determined by saying that we have a "massless particle", i.e. $P^2 = 0$. It is also not uniquely determined for massive particles, where it has the value $W^2 = m^2s(s+1)$ for $s$ the spin of the particle, and spin is after all independent from mass.

While the spin representations of massive particles are induced from representations of the massive little group $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ with spin $s$, the massless little group is $\mathrm{ISO}(2)$, the two-dimensional Euclidean group. This group has only one-dimensional and infinite-dimensional unitary representations. The one-dimensional ones are the ones we usually use in physics, and there $W^\mu = \lambda P^\mu$ holds. There are two of them that are interchanged by parity transformations, so the "usual" massless particle gets a two-dimensional "helicity representation".

The infinite-dimensional ones, also called "continuous spin representations", have  the components of $W$ not parallel to $P$ not vanish and hence non-trivially represented on the space of states. These representations do not seem to appear ordinarily in nature - like the tachyonic representations with $P^2 < 0$ - because they do not lead to consistent causal quantum field theories, though it is hard to find texts that unambiguously state this in modern parlance (see Hirata, *"Quantization of Massless Particles with Continuous Spin"*, Progress of Theoretical Physics 58 (2), 1977).

Therefore, the common assumption that $W^2 = 0$ for massless particles is justified by $W^2 \neq 0$ producing unphysical representations, but it would be nice if this was stated a bit more explicitly in many cases.

Comment: Good point! I was mislead to believe $W^2=0$ for massless particles can be directed shown by algebra. In fact, it is a physical constraint (no continuous spin) that guarantees $W^2=0$, $W^\mu=\sigma p^\mu$ and the helicity is Lorentz invariant (the operator $\frac{\vec{J}\cdot\vec{p}}{|\vec{p}|}$ commutes with boosts).