# Why can photons be used as qubits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I've been studying quantum computers and while it's apparent to me how electrons are used as qubits, through their spin number, it's not as clear what makes a photon a viable candidate to be used as a qubit.

I understand how entanglement between qubits works, and how quantum gates work (though I haven't looked into optical gates yet) but I just can't seem to figure out how a photon could carry information!

Could anyone solve this conundrum? Thanks!

Comment: For a geometric point of view, the state space for photon (of fixed momentum) is represented as a Poincare sphere (see for example https://spie.org/publications/fg05_p10-11_poincare_sphere?SSO=1), which is related to the Bloch sphere picture for ordinary qubits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A photon is a massless spin-1 particle. This means that a photon has exactly two spin states, just like an electron.

Comment: For anyone wondering why a "spin-1 particle" has as many states as the electron as a *spin-1/2* particle and not more, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46643/50583.

Comment: See e.g. "Gauge choice and general solution to equations of motion" in Sec. 4.4 [here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnChalker/theory/lecture-notes.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Just to add, any system that can be in two states can serve as qubit. So any elementary particle having two or more values of spin can be a qubit. Moreover, another parameter of a particle can be used for representing a qubit, for example location (you can have one electron and you are looking where is is placed).

Answer (score 0):

Photons have polarization state, so called right circularly polarized and left circularly polarized.