# Why are $\Delta m = 0$ electronic transitions possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics

Photons have helicity eigenvalues of $h = \pm 1$, with $h \neq 0$. In an absorption process involving a one-electron dipole transition, how can the change in the projected angular momentum of the electronic states vanish, $\Delta m = 0$, if the photon that is absorbed has a non-zero projected angular momentum—where did the angular momentum go?

I've read that this reasoning actually holds true when the projection axis of the helicity and the projection axis of the magnetic quantum number coincide, e.g., when a magnetic field creates a preferential axis for $m$ and one sends light along the same axis (or is this also untrue?).

---

The best explanation I've come up with so far is the following: The fact that the helicity eigenvalue $h = 0$ doesn't exist is equivalent to the photon field missing one degree of freedom due to the gauge freedom (see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265646)). Now if we look at the representations of the spin-1 operators ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins)) and remove the basis state corresponding to the $s_z = 0$ eigenvalue, i.e., the one the gauge field is missing, then we find that with the remaining two eigenstates we can only build the $s_x = 0$ and $s_y = 0$ eigenstates, not the ones with non-zero values of $s_x$ and $s_y$. Therefore, even though there is no helicity eigenvalue of 0, it is possible to measure 0 "spin" as long as the axis along which we are measuring is not the propagation axis.

Thus, transitions with $\Delta m = 0$, requiring the projected angular momentum of the photon to be zero, are possible if and only if the direction in which we are measuring the photon spin, or more generally the photon angular momentum, is orthogonal to the photon's propagation direction. Specifically, in the Zeeman case discussed above, the $\Delta m = 0$ transition is possible *only* if the photon propagation direction has a component that is orthogonal to the magnetic field.

Is this correct? If so: I haven't found this reasoning in any book or reference yet, do you know of any?